# Ideas for safe connection from panel-mounted socket to PCB

Tags: pcb, connector, safety, socket

I have a panel-mounted socket with the geometry shown in the images. Inside the enclosure this sockets ends with a male gold-plated pin, diameter 1.9mm.

Any ideas on how to connect from this male pin to the PCB in a way that 1. is safe (strong mating from the pin to whichever female connector is chosen) and 2. can be unplugged for servicing of the PCB if needed? (soldering at both ends of the wire would not be convenient), 3. needs limited space (it is a small encloure).

Note that the 1.9mm male pin at the back of the socket is round. No sleeve available for easy soldering of a wire directly to the socket. It seems easier to find a female socket (RED in the image) that matches de 1.9mm and then solder the wire only at the PCB's end.

Any advice based on experience on how to solve this?

[image: description of the problem to solve]

[image: close-up view of the socket]

Comment: The manufacturer of the socket can probably make something for you. It would be a trivial problem if you could have a connector on the PCB instead of on the socket.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Thanks. Yes, it is somewhat surprising it's been such a struggle to find a right angle or upright PCB solderable DIN42802 compatible socket. And the manufacturer will not be interested in custom developments for the relatively small batches we need.

Comment: Am I mistaken in thinking that part number MS1525-B on page 10 of [this PDF catalogue](http://ec.staubli.com/AcroFiles/Catalogues/MI_Medical_(de-en)_hi.pdf) is the correct flying socket to attach to your connector? The description says "(compatible for mating with terminals such as MEB1,5-R and MLB1,5-R)."

Comment: @andrewmorton You are probably right and MEB panel-mount sockets match MS1525 plugs. But what we are looking for is a short assembly to solder at the back and connect to pcb

Answer (score 1):

You get one like this:
[image: hirschmann 972356100]
(eg: 972356100)
And have small wires with these made:
[image: faston]
This is called faston, and there are cheap male parts for the PCB.

Note: limited amount mating cycles, I'd say about a dozen.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately we need a socket that mates with DIN42802 (see image in my message). The only panel-mount socket we have found ends in a round pin (from multicontact), no chance of properly  soldering to it. We either need to find a socket for 1.9mm round pins or a different manufacturer for 42802 sockets. A challenge so far.

Comment: @EricT Buy DIN42802 molded cable assemblies and solder the wires on the board.

Comment: Please correct me if I missunderstood your previous suggestion. But, the molded DIN42802 cable assembly you propose to use would connect to the socket on the outside of the enclosure, whereas I am looking for a solution for internal connection to the PCB. There is also a space limitation. Ideally I would need a female connector that slides on the male pin of the DIN socket and solder wire from this connector to the PCB. I simply can't find a female for a 1.9mm with adequate geometry.

Comment: On the other hand, the connector you suggested from Hirschmann made me think that it might be possible to find touchproof sockets (with solderable endings like the one you suggested) that, even if not DIN42802, are geometrically compatible with the DIN42802 mating plug. We don't really need to use DIN42802 sockets I now realise, but simply a socket compatible with DIN42802 plugs.

Comment: @EricT You have the DIN42802 male on the inside of the panel right?

Comment: No, the DIN42802 is facing the outside of the panel. The struggle has been to find a manufacturer for this kind of sockets and to decide how to set the connection from the back pin of the socket to the pcb, taking little space and suring it is safe.